# How do I set up PHP to use mail or similar with hMailServer?

Tags: php, email, send, mail-server

My environment is as follows:
-Windows IIS7 + Windows DNS Server (all DNS records and IIS7 settings are fully accessible by me).
-hMailServer with SMTP listening on 25.

I guess that's about it, my actual intentions are as follows:
I want to use WordPress for one of my domains which is pointed to the server, but currently it is unable to send emails (for example password reminders).

My knowledge is not exactly amazing for stuff like this, so be gentle to explain. :>

Comment: I should probably mention here as I forgot to say earlier, I am using php 5.3 non-threaded.

Comment: Issue resolved, I completely forgot to give the API User permissions to execute sendmail.exe! Woops. :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure your SMTP settings in the `php.ini` file (located in the php-directory). If you don't use smtpauth/ssl this will do the trick.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = 192.168.1.10

; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = john@example.com
```

However, the standard php mail function **neither supports smtpauth nor ssl**. Have a look at the [specs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php).

As you are running windows, you can use fake sendmail. This supports auth and ssl. 
Read this [guide](http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/Installing_Fake_Sendmail_for_Windows), and it should work.

Comment: I was under the impression that PHP's generic mail command did not support authentication? If it does, where do I get this username and password from?

Comment: So I re-looked at what you said, and I've realised you were referring to sendmail. I decided to give the fake sendmail a try but I still can't quite get it to work.

Comment: @Uniqu3: it does NOT, i was wrong. I grabbed it from one of our XAMP-machines, don't know why it was there. Edited the answer. Read the guide (link provided above), this should work if properly configured.

Comment: Read that guide whilst I was trying to fix it up. I've had no luck with it.

Comment: @aebersold Does this solution restricted on the LAN machines only?

Comment: No, you can use any SMTP server, LAN or WAN (if the server allows you to connect).